# Browser addition/script to ping me when site changes title

Tags: windows, gratis, web-browser, notification

I would like to know if there is any free application that would let an acoustic sound ping me whenever a specific website title changes to a specific (set of) titles.

This is because the site has some internal messaging but the only notify is the title changing and an icon that lights up (but the exact icon depends on the current skin for the page).

I usually use Chrome but I can try other browsers if they better suite those needs. I'm on Windows 7.

Answers that provide solutions for two browsers at least are better.

Answers that direct me to learning some programming to achieve the results are OK as long as they give me a place where I can actually learn.

---

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11693618) but I'm not sure how to implement it - I program in C++ at best.

Comment: Could this be a userscript that runs on every page? It would work on any *open* tab and would ping you on any tab's `<title>` element change.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ that would be less useful, unless I run a separate browser **window** for the site I want to monitor, or unless A "which title change?" could be useful, but it's a start.

Comment: I could make a userscript that runs on all *running* tabs on *any* window that sounds a small ping and displays an alert `x changed to y`... would that work for you?

Comment: I couldn't actually tell you the number of the tab because this will be a userscript and not a chrome extension - and it will work in all browsers - but it will focus the tab that has the title change when it alerts you.

Comment: It is intended to let me know somebody messaged me without unfocusing my fullscreen application.

Comment: How about an unfocusing html5 notification then?

Comment: It would ping you and show a short notification on the bottom right of your screen saying `x changed to y`.

Comment: Regarding your edit - if *you* want to make something, I highly recommend reading about 'userscripts' - they are made with Javascript and are not too difficult if you know the language....!

Comment: Does the website have any useful RSS feeds?

Comment: @Cybernard what do you mean by useful? Anyway, I don't think so.